# 8 Month old only napping for 30 minutes at a time, Help!

Tags: infant, naps

I am not sure what to do, My baby has a naptime routine, and will pass out instantly. But will always wake up right at 30 minutes.

My wife and I follow his cues, and he typically has a wake window of about 3-4 hours unless he shows signs of tiredness sooner!

Is there any advice or things my wife and I can try to possibly extend these naps?

Comment: Hi Derek. As written, I'm guessing that your baby has interrupted you in the middle of writing this question, so it's a bit unclear what kind of help you need. During one of those 30 minute cycles, can you take another look at this and finish your thoughts in the second sentence?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Whoops, I didn't realize, thanks! Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: Does your baby typically sleep through the night? You state that he has a 'wake window' of 3-4 hours, does this mean that they regularly wake up in the middle of the night?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical No he doesn't. We put him down between 7-8pm and he will wake up around 6am

Comment: Some things you might want to try: parent lies down and rests alongside napping baby; white noise; adjusting room temperature; reduce total number of naps; push the nap start time back a bit; increase physical activity and fresh air.  But I congratulate you on the long night-time sleep.

Answer (score 4):

### Probably Not

At the age you're describing, both of my kids generally started changing whatever the nap routine was that we'd become accustomed to and it sounds like your son's doing the same to you.

I'm not qualified to say whether this is normal or not, just that it's something I've seen twice now so I'm inclined to think it's normal.

If you are looking for a longer naptime, one thing you could try is making his 4 morning hours as interactive as possible from the perspectives of mental and physical stimulation. My son is 2 1/2 now and with some reliability, I can get an hour and a half nap out of him, by keeping him heavily involved in many of the things we're doing.

To exemplify, if we go out for groceries, I hand him most things so that he can put them in the cart. If we are playing together, I will make him bring me toys and make sure that he puts them away. And I will always include a trip to the playground so he can run around and burn off any excess energy remaining.

You'll need to figure out what kinds of things are appropriate for your baby since every baby's different, but you get the idea.